# Non-monospace font for tag edits, answering questions, etc

Tags: feature-request, font

I would prefer to have the textboxes on the Ask Ubuntu website be in a non-monospace font, it makes them more attractive to look at.

Comment: You could change this client side.

Comment: I can, but this is just a suggestion. To make it the default gives the impression of  the site having "smoothed edges".

Comment: I am also suprised by the vote down on this suggestion. All I was doing was making a suggestion that  would improve the visual appeal of the site, if you don't like my suggestion, its no skin off your back.

Comment: Voted back up, because it is an interesting idea (really, people should leave explanations when they downvote). But a potential issue I see here is related to formatting: monospace makes looking at source much nicer for editing purposes because it helps with keeping things aligned properly. Non-mono font would be better used with a true WYSIWYG editor, instead of our current method of using Markdown.

Comment: @William It was not me who voted down. However, note that voting is different on meta compared to the main site. On the meta site voting is used to express agreement or disagreement, see the [faq#vote-differences] for details.

Comment: Thank you for listing your reasons, it was not something I  thought about. And thank yo, NN, for the explanation on the difference on downvoting. I just assumed it would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose? The *preview* is in a proportional font; the actual *editor* is in a monospace font.

I don't see any merit in this request, since both font styles are always available.